# Is it possible to create a quark-gluonic reactor to produce energy with help of strong interaction?

Tags: quarks, gluons, quark-gluon-plasma

Is it possible to create a quark-gluonic reactor to produce energy with help of strong interaction? Can it be done with quark-gluon plasma?

Comment: Every nuclear reactor, be it fission or fusion based is a quark-gluonic reactor using the strong interaction. :-) Other than that... if you have some new principle in mind, where would the energy come from, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the ionic plasma of a fusion reactor was under continuous particle bombardment such that a mixed QCD phase (hadronic + QGP) was being created and sustained. Apparently hadronization of QGP can yield kinetic energy. Possibly there would be places in the phase diagram where the efficiency of the ordinary fusion process is enhanced by this injection of energy.

So the basic design I would propose is, fusion reactor, powering particle accelerator which creates mixed QCD phase in the reactor plasma, increasing the efficiency of the fusion process.